# Javascript eval

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the following working. It seemed to work initially, but somehow it stopped working

```
var setCommonAttr = "1_row1_common";
var val = document.getElementById("abc_" + eval("setCommonAttr")).value;
```

what is wrong with above?

The above code is little different from what I am trying to accomplish. I gave the above example just not to make things complicated here. Below is what I am trying to accomplish:

First I am getting an existing element as follows. The element is a

```
<tr id="row_1_4_2009_abc" class="rowclick">
   <td></td>
</tr>
```

I am using jquery to get the id on click of a row:

```
$(".rowclick").click(function() {
  var row_id = $(this).attr("id");
  var getAttributes = row_id.split("_");
  var setCommonAttr = getAttributes[1] + "_" + getAttributes[2] + "_" + getAttributes[3] + "_" + getAttributes[4];
  var new_row_id = document.getElementById("new_row_" + setCommonAttr).value;
});
```

Comment: Why do you even need the eval?

Comment: The call to eval is completely unnecessary

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do - you're `eval`ing a string literal. Also, why not just `var val = document.getElementById("abc_" + setCommonAttr).value;`

Comment: What do you expect to get from `document.getElementById("new_row_" + setCommonAttr).value;` ? is it an input field?

Comment: @Martin. Yes, it is an hidden input value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will everything be in that form? row_xxx_xxx_xxx_xxx

if so, why not `var new_row_id = document.getElementById("new_" + row_id).value;`

Comment: no, I am cutting the first part in row_id. I am splitting "row_id" and ignoring the first part when forming other ids.

Comment: Yes, but the first components of the new ID, in your example are 'new_row_', so you have 'new_' + 'row_.....' which is the same thing as stripping off the first component ( 'row_' ) and adding 'new_row_' to the beginning -- if everything doesn't have 'row_' at the beginning, then this wouldn't work,

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't need eval() to do this. The value you want is already a variable in JavaScript. Try:

```
var setCommonAttr = "1_row1_common";
var val = document.getElementById("abc_" + setCommonAttr).value;
```

Comment: I edited my question with another sample code to show what I am trying to do

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call eval().

You can just concatenate the string with the variable:

```
var setCommonAttr = "1_row1_common"; var val = document.getElementById("abc_" +   setCommonAttr).value;
```